# Query only managers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table and try to retrieve only managers: 1,2,7,11,12
I wrote this query and would like to know if there is a better way to retrieve those answers.

```
  select * 
  from employees emp
  where exists (select *
  from employees mng
  where mng.mangid=emp.emp_id )
  union
  select * 
  from employees
  where mngid is null

Empid   Name      Mngid
1       Alvin     NULL
2       Jose      1
3       Amado     1
4       Stuart    1
5       Demarcus  2
6       Mark      2
7       Merlin    2
8       Elroy     7
9       Charles   7
10      Rudolph   7
11      bob       NULL
12      danis     NULL
```

Comment: What does "better" mean? How would you know an alternative solution was better?

Comment: I guess the select from employee where mangid is null should be enough

Comment: for each manager  You want only the related  empID  or all the columns content ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select distinct isnull(emp2.Empid, emp1.Empid) Empid, emp2.[Name], emp2.Mngid
from employees emp1
join employees emp2 on isnull(emp1.Mngid, emp1.Empid) = emp2.Empid
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d5a45dba90ec941a3221393d175f95a)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a inner join on subquery for avoid scope issue

```
select e.*
from employees e
inner join (
    select DISTINCT Mngid 
    from employees  
) t on t.Mngid = e.Empid
UNION 
select * 
from employees
where mngid is null
```